# Does torch.save() overwrite the previous saved model which was saved in the same path?

Tags: torch

If i use torch.save() every epoch, does it overwrite the previous one? The task_id is '0', so the path is always './0checkpoint.pth.jar'.

```py
def save_checkpoint(state, is_best,task_id, filename='checkpoint.pth.tar'):
    f = open('./' + task_id + filename, 'w')

    torch.save(state, './' + task_id + filename)
    if is_best:
        shutil.copyfile('./' + task_id + filename, './' + task_id + 'model_best.pth.tar')
        
    f.close()
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Hello, I am running the code on the Kaggle. I can't know whether the output is the newest since it seems always to be '/kaggle/working/0checkpoint.pth.jar'